# Can we lower bound $\frac{(\sum a_i)^k}{\mathbb{E}[(\sum b_i)^k]}$ by a single component?

Tags: real-analysis

I have one ratio, where $a_i>0$ and $b_i$ is a positive random variable, $k \ge 2$ is a positive real value.

\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\right)^k}{\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^n b_i\right)^k\right]} \ge ??
\end{equation}

Then, I want to obtain a lower bound which is a function of only $a_i, b_i$. For example, can we take this kind of bound for some $j$? It is okay to change its functional form, but what I need is only a function of $a_j, b_j$.

\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\right)^k}{\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^n b_i\right)^k\right]} \ge \frac{a_j^k}{\mathbb{E}\left[b_j^k\right]}
\end{equation}

Note: the following inequality would be helpful.
\begin{equation}
\frac{\sum A_i}{\sum B_i} \ge \min_i \left( \frac{A_i}{B_i}\right)
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

Since your sums appear to be finite, you *can* use the fact that
$$ \left( \sum_{i=1}^n b_i \right)^k \leq  \left(n\cdot \max_i b_i \right) ^k$$
which we can write as $nb_{\small \mbox{max}}^k$ for short.  When you invert this, the $\leq$ becomes a $\geq$ as usual.  However, I'm not sure how that will interact with your ${\mathbb E}$ operator -- if that depends intrinsically on the $b_i$ then you are going to need to look at how you're defining it and find an inequality specific to that.

Similarly you can bound the numerator by 
$$\left( \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \right)^k \geq \left( n \cdot \min_i a_i \right)^k$$
assuming that these are independent of the $b_i$ in the denominator.

Comment: Your first comment is incorrect: min_i should be 1/2 so the inequality holds. Anyway, your comment may help my case. Thanks.

Comment: @LBgood thanks for the catch, I calculated $\min_i A_i/\min_i B_i$ instead.  I've removed that paragraph since it's false :)